# Append stacktrace of caller thread into the new thread being created, for easier debugging

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, stack-trace, printstacktrace

I have frequently faced a problem while debugging.

Sometimes a thread ends throwing an exception.

And the reason of that issue is the caller/starter of the thread.

The caller send incorrect parameter or called the thread without initializing something.

In order to find from where the particular thread was called, it takes a little extra effort,
as the stacktrace is useless.

What if we could append the stacktrace of the caller thread into the called thread.

Consider the following example :

```
public class ThreadTest {
        Thread t = new Thread("executeNonBlocking") {
            @Override public void run() {
                // What would be a good way to 
                // append callerStackTrace to the stack
                // trace of this thread
                System.out.println("inside");
                new Throwable().printStackTrace();
            }
        };

    public void executeNonBlocking() {
        final StackTraceElement[] callerStackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
        new Throwable().printStackTrace();
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest().executeNonBlocking();
    }
}
```

Output

```
java.lang.Throwable
        at ThreadTest.executeNonBlocking(ThreadTest.java:27)
        at ThreadTest.main(ThreadTest.java:41)
inside
java.lang.Throwable
        at ThreadTest$1.run(ThreadTest.java:34)
```

Desired output

```
java.lang.Throwable
        at ThreadTest.executeNonBlocking(ThreadTest.java:27)
        at ThreadTest.main(ThreadTest.java:41)
inside
java.lang.Throwable
        at ThreadTest.executeNonBlocking(ThreadTest.java:27)
        at ThreadTest.main(ThreadTest.java:41)
        at ThreadTest$1.run(ThreadTest.java:34)
```

---

Edit : Here is the solution obtained after discussions with @peter-lawrey

```
public class StackTraceInheritingThread {

    private final Runnable r;

    private volatile Thread th = null;
    private String title;
    private boolean daemon;

    private InheritedStackTrace ist ;

    private static final ThreadLocal<InheritedStackTrace> tl = new ThreadLocal<InheritedStackTrace>();

    public StackTraceInheritingThread(Runnable r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    private final class StackTraceInheritingUncaughtExceptionHandler implements  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        @Override public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            if(ist!=null){ 
                e.addSuppressed(ist);
            }
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

    }

    public StackTraceInheritingThread setName(String nm){
        this.title = nm;
        return this;
    }

    public StackTraceInheritingThread setDaemon(boolean daemon) {
        this.daemon = daemon;
        return this;
    }

    public void start(){
        if(th!=null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already started");
        }

        th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                tl.set(ist);
                r.run();
            }
        },title);
        th.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new StackTraceInheritingUncaughtExceptionHandler());
        if(daemon)th.setDaemon(true);
        ist = new InheritedStackTrace();
        th.start();
    }

    public static Throwable getInheritedStackTrace(){
        return tl.get();
    }

    public static StackTraceInheritingThread make(Runnable r1){
        return new StackTraceInheritingThread(r1);
    }


    private static final class InheritedStackTrace extends Exception {

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackTraceInheritingThread.make(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("heelo");
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }).setName("ExperimentalThread").start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the Throwable used to create a thread in a thread local variable.

```
public enum Throwables {
    ;

    private static final InheritableThreadLocal<Throwable> STARTING_THREAD = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(Throwable t) {
        STARTING_THREAD.set(t);
    }

    public static Throwable get() {
        return STARTING_THREAD.get();
    }

    public static void printStartingThrowable() {
        Throwable throwable = get();
        if (throwable == null) return;
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static Thread start(Runnable run, String name, boolean daemon) {
        Throwable tmp = new Throwable("Started here");
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                set(tmp);
                run.run();
            }
        }, name);
        t.setDaemon(daemon);
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        try {
            method();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("\nThrown in " + Thread.currentThread());
            t.printStackTrace();
            printStartingThrowable();
        }

        start(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    method();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    System.err.println("\nThrown in " + Thread.currentThread());
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    printStartingThrowable();
                }
            }
        }, "Test thread", false);

    }

    private static void method() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Thrown in Thread[main,5,main]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at Throwables.method(Throwables.java:59)
    at Throwables.main(Throwables.java:36)

Thrown in Thread[Test thread,5,main]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at Throwables.method(Throwables.java:59)
    at Throwables.access$000(Throwables.java:1)
    at Throwables$2.run(Throwables.java:47)
    at Throwables$1.run(Throwables.java:26)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.lang.Throwable: Started here
    at Throwables.start(Throwables.java:21)
    at Throwables.main(Throwables.java:43)
```

Comment: What you have suggested will have to be done manually. Imagine the amount of code that will have to be changed. And an exception is thrown when it is not caught. It means, I do not know in advance that at which line the exception will be thrown.
What I need is, irrespective of where the exception is thrown in the called thread, the stacktrace of caller is also appended to it.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @ShashankTulsyan It doesn't matter where it is thrown, only where it is printed.  You can add a handleExcdeption(t) method so this code to add the caller only occurs in one place.

Comment: I found this method
    public void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)

I think this is a good way to print customize output for unhandled exceptions. In the custom handler which I send, I could print the stacktrace of the caller method. Let me try this out.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have posted a solution in my question, is that what you really meant ? @peter

Comment: That would work for uncaught exceptions.  You could also set a thread local for caught exceptions as well.

Comment: Good idea, that was the immediate next thing I had in my mind. +1 to your answer. BTW @peter can you edit your actual answer, because it way to different from the solution which we arrived to, other people referring to this might get really confused.

Comment: @ShashankTulsyan added an example where the same code will work in a started thread or not.

Comment: I mixed your code and mine, and created a sort of library out of this. This method that you made - printStartingThrowable(); is a cool concept. @peter

Comment: @ShashankTulsyan I think it's useful if it can be called even if it is  there is no starting thread.  Also you could print just the stack trace so the Throwable doesn't appear to avoid confusion.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say. And for some reason , I am unable to use @ tags at the starting. @peter

Comment: When you reply to someone's answer or question you don't need the @.  Instead of printing the whole exception, you can get the stackTrace and just print that.

Comment: The only problem is, the performance is going to be really very bad, and usage of this utility will have to be done, only in cases where the speed doesn't matter that much.

Comment: The performance impact is small compared to the cost of starting a thread or even the cost of a long log message. You could cache the stack trace as a String if you expect to print it many times. I would also trim the stack trace printed to improve performance and readability.